# How to have multiple file names while uploading with multer

Tags: node.js, multer

My code is as shown below:

```
const multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();
let profile_image = '';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/images')
    },
    filename(req, file, callback) {
        profile_image = `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        callback(null, profile_image);
    }
});


const userData = (req, res) => {
    upload = multer({
        limits: {
            fileSize: 1000000,
            files: 2
        },
        storage,
        fileFilter(req, file, callback) {
            const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
            if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
                return callback(res.end('Only images are allowed'), null)
            }
            callback(null, true);
        }
    }).any();
    upload(req, res, err => {

        const foodtruck_name = req.body.foodtruck_name;
        const foodtruck_tag = req.body.foodtruck_tag;
        console.log(`foodname${foodtruck_name}`);
        console.log("error" + err);
        console.log("profile image" + profile_image);
        if ((!foodtruck_name) || (foodtruck_name.trim() == '')) {
            console.log("fooddddname  " + foodtruck_name);
            res.json({
                status: '404',
                message: 'Please enter valid foodtruck name'
            });
        } else {

            const truck = new foodTruck();
            truck.foodtruck_name = foodtruck_name,
                truck.foodtruck_tag = foodtruck_tag,
                awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image).then((result) => {
                    truck.foodtruck_img = "https://myWebsite.com/" +
                        profile_image;
                    awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image).then((result) => {
                        truck.foodtruck_logo = "https://myWebsite.com/" +
                            profile_image;
                        truck.save((err, trucSaved) => {
                            res.json({
                                status: '200',
                                message: 'Thanks for registering with quflip',
                                data: trucSaved
                            });
                        });
                    }).catch((errMsg) => {
                        res.json({
                            status: '400',
                            message: errMsg
                        })
                    });
                }).catch((errMsg) => {
                    res.json({
                        status: '400',
                        message: errMsg
                    })
                });
        }

    });

};
```

Here, I am able to upload multiple images successfully , but I am not able to get the names for each individual file while uploading. how can I have them inside  `upload(req, res, err => {`  function?